# simple understanding of 'for' loop in polymorphism

Tags: python

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):    
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):              
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclass must implement abstract method")

class Cat(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Meow!'

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Woof! Woof!'

animals = [Cat('Missy'),
           Dog('Lassie')]

for animal in animals:
    print animal.name + ': ' + animal.talk()
```

I want to know why "**for animal in animals**" animals is taken? what is that **animals** stand for??
here the class name is animal.

Comment: `animals` is a `list` containing a `Cat` and a `Dog` object. Is that your question? `for animal in animals` loops over this list one element at a time (`animal` becomes the current item in the list it's working on and prints the animal's name and 'speech')

Comment: You should probably first take a basic Python tutorial before starting on OO. Lists and iteration are pretty fundamental.

Comment: You should replace `class Animal:` with `class Animal(object):` when working in Python 2 as you are, because otherwise it's an old-style class, and you don't want to mess with them.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop in Python is actually a [for-each](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loop.  We iterate through each element (which we refer to as `animal`) in the collection (which we refer to as `animals`).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a `for` loop in python. The statement is iterates over the ordered collection (a list, a string or a file object), in your case it is a list of `Animal`. And the choice of word (for `object` in `objects`) is a tradition from python.

Take a look at this code and see if you understand it better :)

```
iceCreams = ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate'] # A list of ice cream flavors
toppings = ['Gummy Bear', 'Cookies', 'Nuts', 'Chips']  # A list of toppings

# Looping through the ice creams
# for each ice cream in the ice cream list
for iceCream in iceCreams:
    # Looping through the toppings
    # for each topping in the topping list
    for topping in toppings:
        print('I like', iceCream, 'ice cream with', topping)
```

Output:

```
I like Vanilla ice cream with Gummy Bear
I like Vanilla ice cream with Cookies
I like Vanilla ice cream with Nuts
I like Vanilla ice cream with Chips
I like Chocolate ice cream with Gummy Bear
I like Chocolate ice cream with Cookies
I like Chocolate ice cream with Nuts
I like Chocolate ice cream with Chips
```

Hope this help you understand how it work, as well as using it in a nested form.

Answer (score 0):

animals is a list of the classes you have defined with the line

```
animals = [Cat('Missy'), Dog('Lassie')]
```

The `for animal in animals:` line is called syntactic sugar, and is just an easier way of doing a traditional for loop.  The iterator variable in this case is called animal, and is equal to each element of the animals list that you created with the above command.